# Issues with NSDate's earlierDate in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Before iOS 5, I could use the `==` operator to check the returned date from `earlierDate`:

```
if ([aDate earlierDate:bDate] == aDate)
    [someone doSomething];
```

But now, I have to do this:

```
if ([[aDate earlierDate:bDate] isEqualToDate:aDate])
    [someone doSomething];
```

Why would this be so?

Actually, the issue is with using `==` for comparison vs. using `isEqualToDate:`, and less to do with the `earlierDate:` call.

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing?  I just dropped this code into an iOS 5 app building for iOS 5 targets and there's no compiler or runtime errors.

Comment: No error; the `==` comparison was giving expected behavior before iOS 5. Now to see the same behavior, I have to use `isEqualToDate:`.

Answer (score 6):

You had been using pointer comparison (`==`), and now you have to use the object's comparison method. That means that in earlier versions of iOS, the `earlierDate:` method would return the object you passed in that was earlier. Now, it seems to make a new object (with the same data as the earlier date) and returns that.

The `isEqualToDate:` method is preferred as it is more appropriate, and is less likely to break like your pointer comparison did.

Comment: The problem is that the docs for iOS 5 still say that `earlierDate` returns one of the two objects (`aDate` or `bDate`). Based on that information, I **should** be ideally using `==` for (pointer)  comparison rather than possibly a more costly comparison method for equality.

Comment: Then maybe it's a new bug. File a bug report with Apple and see what falls out.

Comment: Yes, my radar for the issue was closed as behaves as expected, as expected.